# WebResponse.getOutputStream() in Wicket 1.5?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

This code was working for me in 1.4:

```
WebResponse response = (org.apache.wicket.request.http.WebResponse) getResponse();
response.setAttachmentHeader("List.xls");
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(out);
.....
.....
workbook.write();
workbook.close();
```

I see in 1.5 that there is no WebResponse.getOutputStream() - but it was not marked as deprecated?

I have looked in the 1.5 migration guide but I can't see any obvious solution.

Can someone please tell me how I should be doing this in 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap `Response` in an `OutputStream`:

```
public final class ResponseOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private final Response response;
    private final byte[] singleByteBuffer = new byte[1];
    public ResponseOutputStream(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        singleByteBuffer[0] = (byte) b;
        write(singleByteBuffer);
    }
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        response.write(b);
    }
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (off == 0 && len == b.length) {
            this.write(b);
        } else {
            super.write(b, off, len);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. I am not in a position to test yet.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed yesterday. Will be part of Wicket 1.5.4.
But for this use case you should use a resource. See the implementation of ResourceLink.

Comment: I am using the jExcelAPI library.
I need to give an OutputStream as a parameter to Workbook.createWorkbook
I am not writing the output to disk - want to stream it directly to the browser.
Will your suggestion work for this?

Comment: Yes it will - you use a ResourceLink to hold a Resource, e.g. an AbstractResource.